# Instantaneous Voltage of Generator / Radian / Angular Frequency Question Lack of Understanding

Tags: voltage

I'm training to be an electrician and am struggling to understand this formula any help would be appreciated.

The formula is $V_s = V_0\sin(\omega t)$ I believe this is the formula for instantaneous voltage of a generator

Now from my understanding and please correct me where I go wrong, $V_s$ is the instantaneous voltage at the time stated in the formula?

$V_0$ is the peak voltage

$(\omega t)$ is supposed to be the angular frequency? if we took an assumed 230V Peak 60Hz supply for example a full sinusoidal AC wave would occur 60 times per second? and $(\omega t)$ is supposed to be an angular representation of this movement represented in radians, $(\omega t)$ is equal to $(2\pi fT(s))$, $2\pi$ is because $2\pi$ radians $= 360^\circ$, the frequency is = 60 so the rotation is happening 60 times per second given that $T(s) = 1$. $\omega t$ is how fast it's rotating?

I'm confused as to how the $\sin()$ part operates, I'd guess $V_0$ is the limiting factor to ensure the formula doesn't go outside of the bounds of possibility but what does it actually do, I believe it's to do with triangles but I'm not sure. I'm not really sure where to begin to understand this apart from maybe revisiting trigonometry. $\sin$(opposite/hypotenuse) is where I'm at but can't visualise where triangles fit in here and how it can pinpoint the point in the wave at time $s$ is?

Please help :'(

Comment: I’m not sure I even grasp what you’re asking with the “how the sine function works” part… It is a function. It returns the value of the function for a particular input, and the value of the function happens to oscillate over a particular domain of the inputs. It’s as simple as plug and chug.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is what exactly does the sine function do like step by step, does it differ depending on input?, for example I read online sin(23) returns 0.39073110, it achieves this via converting 23 to radians, then doing a complex calculation

Comment: $\omega=\frac{2\pi}T$ is the angular frequency where $T$ is the period. $\omega t$ is a phase, which corresponds to an angle if you want to visualise the triangle that is implied by the use of the trigonometric function. When we say 230V, that is a root-mean-squared value, so, really, $V_0=230\sqrt2$; you will learn this later that AC voltages and currents are deliberately defined this way so that calculation formulæ will be the same as the simple DC cases. In particular, the peaks must overshoot a little. Yes, you need to revise trigonometry.

Comment: This is really more of a math question than a physics question.  I would recommend going over Chapters 5 and 6 of [this precalculus textbook](https://openstax.org/details/books/precalculus-2e) to brush up on these concepts.

Answer (score 0):

> $(\omega{}t)$ is supposed to be the angular frequency?

No. The angular frequency is just $\omega$. It's a number of radians per second. $t$ is elapsed time in seconds. When you multiply radians per second by seconds, you just get a number of radians—an angle. $(\omega{}t)$ tells how far the system has "rotated" since the start time, $t=0$.* The argument of the sin function always is an angle.

There are $2\pi$ radians in a full cycle, so if the frequency is 60 cycles per second, then $\omega$ is approximately $377.0$ radians per second. That's because $60\cdot{}2\pi\approx377.0$.

> I guess what I'm asking is what exactly does the sine function do, like step by step?

It doesn't *do* anything. It doesn't have "steps." $\sin(\pi/6)$ equals $0.5$. It just does. It *always* equals 0.5. $\sin(\pi/2)=1$, $\sin(\pi)=0$. Those are just facts that never change. If you don't know the sin of some number ($\sin(1.234)=\text{?}$ for example) then a mathematician could tell you steps to calculate its approximate value; but the steps don't define the sin function. It's the other way 'round. The mathematician figured out the steps *from* the definition.

> the rotation is happening 60 times per second given that $T(s)=1$.

I'm not sure what you are trying to say. The elapsed time in your original formula is just $t$. It's the number of seconds since some arbitrary starting time. At the start, $t=0$. Three seconds later, $t=3$, etc.

> The formula is $V_s=V_0\sin(\omega{}t)$.

So, $V_s$, in that case is the instantaneous voltage at time $t$. I don't know what the $s$ signifies because the voltage at time $t=0$ is *not* $V_0$. The voltage at time $t=0$ is just zero because $\sin(0)=0$.

$V_0$ is the *peak* voltage. It's the RMS voltage times the square root of two, as naturallyInconsistent mentioned in a comment. The peak voltage occurs whenever $\sin(\omega{}t)=1$, which is the greatest value that the sin function reaches. $\sin(x)$ can be anywhere between -1 and 1, depending on the value of $x$.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_and_cosine for more info on the topic.

---

* Exactly the same as how, if you multiply miles per hour times hours, you get miles. If you drive for four hours at 60 miles per hour, you'll have gone 240 miles since time $t=0$.